# Magento - Associated products are not showing under configurable product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento Community Edition 1.9.3.2.

I created configurable product and created an associated products also. My issue is,

1. Configurable products are not displaying front page
2. Associated products also not displaying backend. but if i click on
   reset filter button it is showing simple products which belongs to
   some other configurable products.

[image]

[image]

And i have checked:

Stock Availability 
Qty
Website
Visibility
Catalog
Price

All are correct. Does any one know what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

After click on reset filter it does not show wrong products. It shows all the simple products which can assign to this configurable product. Just click on checkbox for the product which you want to associate and click on save button then the checked products will be associated to this configurable product.